# Python: sqlalchemy not recognized

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pycharm

I have installed a module called Google Scraper (https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper) and I copied this code from his profile:

```
import sys
from GoogleScraper import scrape_with_config, GoogleSearchError
from GoogleScraper.database import ScraperSearch, SERP, Link

def basic_usage():
# See in the config.cfg file for possible values
config = {
    'SCRAPING': {
        'use_own_ip': 'True',
        'keyword': 'Let\'s go bubbles!',
        'search_engines': 'yandex',
        'num_pages_for_keyword': 1
    },
    'SELENIUM': {
        'sel_browser': 'chrome',
    },
    'GLOBAL': {
        'do_caching': 'False'
    }
}

try:
    sqlalchemy_session = scrape_with_config(config)
except GoogleSearchError as e:
    print(e)

# let's inspect what we got

for search in sqlalchemy_session.query(ScraperSearch).all():
    for serp in search.serps:
        print(serp)
        for link in serp.links:
            print(link)
```

There should a list of links printed, but nothing happens. I guess that the SQLalchemy part is not recognized... I have not used this before. I installed a module called SQLalchemy but do I need to set up something else? What could cause this code not to work?

Comment: How did you install sqlalchemy? what system do you use? Are you certain the installation was correct? If you installed it with pip, the final output should be `Successfully installed sqlalchemy`. What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: I use PyCharm and I installed sqlalchemy with pip, yes I got the success message. I do not get an error message, but the code just does not do what it's supposed to do. The 'sqlalchemy_session' is not recognized.